# How should I get matched data in Trimatch?

Tags: r, match

I usually used matchit.
At this time, I used trimatch for the comparison of the three groups after matching.

When I use matchit, I can get the data after matching like below

```
m.out=matchit(treat~age,data=res,method="nearest",ratio=1)
m.data1 <- match.data(m.out,distance ="pscore")
```

But, I can't get the data after matching in trimatch.
How can I get it?

From Korea

Comment: Welcome to SO, Your question is not very to clear to me. Please provide a reproducible example.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. You need to ask the package creator for some instructions on using the package. As it is, it is poorly documented.